# Phonegap/Jquery Camera API - Capture image

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, android-camera, data-url

This is my first phonegap or jquery mobile app. I'm trying to make a simple web app that will use native functionality to access the camera/capture api.

I can't find a good piece of example code that shows me how to say what the DATA_URL is - do I just leave this code as it is and the Data url is generated, or do I need to point towards the SD or localStorage for example?

Please note I am building this app as a web app, using phonegap build in Dreamweaver cs6.

The example function on the phonegap website is:

```
function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }
```

the website is mobli-fi.co.uk for

Answer (score 1):

**destinationType.DATA_URL** only means that file will be returned as a base64 encoded string. This will be forwarded as a parameter to the successful call back function.

Because newer mobile phones can produce larger files it is advised to use a FILE_URI option.

```
Camera.DestinationType = {
    DATA_URL : 0,                // Return image as base64 encoded string
    FILE_URI : 1                 // Return image file URI
};
```

Here you will find more: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera. Seach for the cameraOptions.

Example:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 25, destinationType: 
    Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

}
```

Because **Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI** is used, call back function will receive an imageURI. Or BASE64 encoded string representation of the taken picture in case of **DestinationType.DATA_URL**.